# Extract Inline Queries from .Net Application

Tags: .net, inline-code

I have a .Net application which uses Inline Queries in abundance. As part of a performance improvement initiative, I want to extract all the inline queries being used across the .Net application into a Text file or Excelsheet. IS there any way to avoid the manual effort for this activity? Are there any tools available? Please let me know how to extract this information with minimal manual effort?

```
try
            {                    
                dbextraction.initParameters();
                dbextraction.AddParameters("dtDate", "Date/Time", dtDate);
                dbextraction.SqlPrepareAndExecute(ref hSqlVal, objFilter.VarSqlFilter("    Select name , id from "+ dbextraction.dbowner + "employee where a23_status = 'Active'"));
            }
catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ExternalLogger.LogError(ex, this, ExternalLogger.GetEmployeeDetails());
                dbextraction.Var_SqlError();
            }
```

Comment: What is an "inline query"? Raw SQL query? Can you post an example?

Comment: Write a Roslyn application to find any strings that start with a SQL keyword. You might get some false positives, of course.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta .. I just gave an example of the inline query.